# Get a reference to a file saved at compile time

Tags: android, android-file

I have a text file which I'll be using to populate my database. The easiest way I found to use this file is using `.import` statement of `SQLite`. The statement will be something like this.

```
.import  <myFileName>  <myTableName>
```

However, I don't know where to save this text file. The most basic choice is `res/raw` folder. But then how to get a reference to this `File` ?

I must emphasize on the fact that I want a reference of the file and not read it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can in general cannot get real file handles of files that do not exist. Ressources and Assets are compiled into your apk, and thus no regular files.

---

If you wish to ship your application with a database, you can use the asset folder. There is [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database) about that. The basic method is that you create the whole database at compile-time (using some tool for sqlite databases, for example [SQLite database browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/)) and ship that database file as asset. Then you can [extract the database file from assets](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) and use the newly created database file.

Comment: `SQLiteAssetHelper`, in particular, is a great way to solve the ship-the-database-with-the-app problem: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper